# ANTLR4 using subrules when defining precedence

Tags: antlr, antlr4

Here is a snippet of my really simple grammar:

```
function
    :   'not' function
    |   function 'and' function
    |   function 'or' function
    ;
```

Since I use visitors generated by the library, to make code cleaner I would like to create an sub rule as following:

```
unaryFunction
    :  'not' function
    ;
function
    :  unaryFunction
    |  function 'and' function
    |  function 'or' function
    ;
```

This way in the visitor code there will be an extra method

```
visitUnaryFunctionContext(Parser.UnaryFunctionContext ctx)
```

So when I enter this block I already know it's NOT some_function and save a lot of checks.

But I found if I create a sub rule "unaryFunction" the precedence breaks. In the second sample of grammar the precedence of word "not" is lower than "and"/"or".

Is this a limitation of antlr4? To define precedence do I have to put all rules in one single place?

Comment: Effectively answered [previously](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39318783/detect-tokens-triggering-rules-in-antlr4/39320210#39320210).

Comment: @GRosenberg Thank you so much! That works.